# How to install Jacoco plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jacoco

I'm running Jenkins 1.627, and I'm **having problems to install JaCoCo plugin** into it the usual way from management UI.

I was able to install number of other plugins without issues, but for JaCoCo plugin the installation fails with exception below, which indicates something wrong with the archive. Indeed, when I download from the link below using browser it downloads only ~7kb hpi file, even though the expected size is >5MB. I tried several older versions as well and same result.

Why is this? Was anyone successful in installing the plugin?

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jacoco/1.0.19/jacoco.hpi (redirected to: http://jenkins.mirror.isppower.de/plugins/jacoco/1.0.19/jacoco.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:797)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1148)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1309)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Inconsistent file length: expected 5196617 but only got 6808
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:784)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your exception message

> Failed to download from
> http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jacoco/1.0.19/jacoco.hpi
> (redirected to:
> http://jenkins.mirror.isppower.de/plugins/jacoco/1.0.19/jacoco.hpi)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Inconsistent file length: expected
> 5196617 but only got 6808

Looks like the file is(was) missing on the specific mirror. Try again, because the url http://jenkins.mirror.isppower.de/plugins/jacoco/1.0.19/jacoco.hpi returned 404 when I started to write my answer and returned 200 at the end

Comment: I tried several times, still only 7kb hpi file is downloaded. I solved this by building the plugin from source and installing manually. I wasn't able to download the correct binary anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

- Step 1: Download http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jacoco.hpi and put it into your **$JENKINS_HOME/plugins** folder.
- Step 2: Restart Jenkins. Done.

#### Solution 2

- Step 1: Download http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jacoco.hpi
- Step 2: Goto http://your_jenkins_url/pluginManager/advanced, from the **Upload Plugin** section, upload your **jacoco.hpi** and restart Jenkins. Done.